# bash script- change string in a file in all directories

Tags: linux, bash, clojure

how can i write a **script in bash**
that:
go to a directory A
run on all directories in A and look for another directory B (which is in part of these directories in A)
after find B need to change a string with another string in a clj file

thank's

Comment: Hello Jordey, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is not dead and we are not rejecting it. it's temporarily "on hold" while we wait for you to edit the question to make it easier to tell if an answer is "correct" or not. Could you please include an example of what the directory structure could look like and what change you would like to each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your question is a little vague, but perhaps something like

```
find A -name B -execdir sed 's/string/another string/g' somefile.clj
```

Best of luck.